# Making stored procedure with input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to make a stored procedure that takes an input parameter. That parameter is name of a patient. All i want is to get that name's ID and add these ID and name to a new table. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. [Example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/). (You could google this, as I just did).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError please read the post after the edit

Comment: Yeah it's possible, although an odd requirement to make a whole new table just for one row. But yeah you can do whatever you like, in theory. Again, google it if you don't know how to write it. Make the procedure, pass the parameter, select the data. If you find data, store it into variables, create a new table, insert the variable data into the new table.

Comment: @ADyson Thankyou i'll try it

Comment: in that case if it's just adding data to another existing table then skip the create table bit and just do an INSERT...SELECT statement, should be possible to do it in one statement. Although if you're accepting a name you probably need to deal with the possibility of duplicate results, or no rows, or spelling mistakes etc etc etc. If possible the user should have identified the correct patient (e.g. by using a search) well before you get to the stage of adding an appointment, and then you just pass the unique patient ID into the create appointment procedure.

Comment: And don't add the name to the appointment table, that's just duplicating data. If the patient sends in a change of name later then your appointment table becomes out of data. Instead you can just add the patient ID, and if you need to get their name in association with the appointment then just JOIN back to the patient table.